# Local Notifications for Meteor/Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor

Has anyone implemented them successfully? Looking for something to work on Android and ios and the [katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) is throwing a compile error when running on android. Thanks in advance!

Compile error i'm getting with katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications:

```
    /Users/example/Documents/EXAMPLE/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification/LocalNotification.java:495:
   error: cannot find symbol
   webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
   ^
   symbol:   method evaluateJavascript(String,<null>)
   location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
```

Comment: If you include the error someone may be able to help.  Otherwise this question will be flagged and closed.

Comment: Compile error now showing

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Answer (score 0):

i also had a problem but added a specific commit version to meteor .meteor/cordova-plugins

```
cordova-plugin-local-notification@https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git#fbcc2e53b76b443456ad1300603c08ab4c1fd52b
```